# Two questions about Dirichlet's characters and roots of unity.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, dirichlet-character

Let $G$ be the units of $\mathbb Z/ q \mathbb Z.$  Let $\chi$ denote Dirichlet character on $G.$ I have two questions.

1. Let $a \in G$ with order $k, $Then it is easy to see that $\chi(a)$ is a $k$ th root of unity. I have to show that for each $k$ th root of unity occurs precisely $ϕ(q)/k$ times among the numbers $χ(a)$ as $χ$ runs over the $ϕ(q)$ Dirichlet characters. My idea is to take a homomorphism $\hat G \to \{k \text{ th roots unity} \}$ defined by $\chi \mapsto \chi(a)/\zeta$ for a fixed $\zeta.$ The kernel is $\{\chi : \chi(a) = \zeta \},$ so it is sufficient to show that the map is surjective which I am not getting how to do.
2. Suppose $\chi$ has order $ k, $ then again $\chi(a)$ is $k$ th root of unity. I need to show that  $k$
   th root of unity occurs precisely $ϕ(q)/k$ times among the
   numbers $χ(a)$ as $a$ runs over $G.$ In this case my attempt is to define the following homomorphism $G \to \{k \text{ th roots unity} \}$ defined by $a \mapsto \chi(a)/\zeta. $ The kernel is $ \{a : \chi(a) = \zeta \} $ so again it is enough to show the map is onto in which I need aid.

Are there are any other methods to do this?

Comment: Neither map is a homomorphism as stated—one needs to not divide by $\zeta$. But surjectivity is still all you need to establish what you want in both cases. Can you prove that the order of $\chi$ is equal to the least common multiple of all the orders of $\chi(a)$ as $a$ varies? Can you then prove that some element $a$ actually has order equal to this least common multiple? This should provide a path towards surjectivity for #2. (And #1 should be essentially the same as #2, with all $\chi$s turned into $a$s and vice versa.)